# When I remove the server name from my header (rewrite rule in IIS) makes my xml corrupt

Tags: xml, iis

I am using a rewrite rule in IIS [remove un wanted http response headers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/varunm/2013/04/23/remove-unwanted-http-response-headers/), using 3. Using URLRewrite.

This works like a charm. and my new response server header is
Server :

But when I want to make an XML document it is not correct:

```
26
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
1000
<bpxml versie="3.1"><CV>etc
```

There are hexadecimal numbers of the size of the line the XML is cut into chunks. When the line is large then it is cut into parts of 1000. These numbers are put into my XML and I can not use the XML.

When I disable the rewrite rule the header lookes like
Server : Microsoft-IIS/8.0

and my XML is correct and comes out nicely

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bpxml versie="3.1"><CV> etc
```

All others headers are the same just the server name is empty. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for your replies

Comment: I assume there's also a header indicating `Transfer-encoding: chunked`?

Comment: That is correct, mist that i my question

Comment: Then your data is valid and correct. It may be the case that your client doesn't understand chunked encoding (even though it is defined as part of HTTP/1.1)

Comment: The data is fine. For security reasons I want to remove the serer name, but now the XML made goes wrong and I cannot pu my finger around what goes wrong. When I disable the rule the client can work fine with the XML provided. All my other  normal pages are working fine

Comment: The XML isn't wrong - whatever is interpreting the HTTP traffic is

Comment: You are correct but  what part goes wrong. The output is not an XML document anymore. The XML document that is made has these lines in it so my application cannot read it as the document is not XML. I use a classic asp page to make my XML if this helps

Comment: How are you handling the HTTP conversation in your client? It sounds like you're doing this via socket code, and haven't implemented the encoding mechanisms in HTTP/1.1 (but are declaring support for HTTP/1.1)

Comment: tin_2010034_lprevo_20161101091805059000.tmp is the file name that is made and that should be tin_2010034_lprevo_20161101091805059000.tmp.xml. The application that should read the file support http1.1 as in : https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SynCrtSock.pas